# How configure GCE to allow communication for mpi

Tags: mpi, google-compute-engine, openmpi

I created an instance-group with 8 instances. All instances have identical programs. Even though I checked two boxes: Allow HTTP traffic and Allow HTTPS traffic during creation, it seems like I still struggle running `mpirun -n 8 --hostfile host_file hostname` which hangs. The host file includes internal IPs of all instances and all instances store the same host file. I also tried not using host file and provide hosts one by one. On a single VM all mpi programs worked as expected. How can I configure GCE to allow mpi communication?

Comment: The easiest way is to allow all IP traffic between your VMs, and configure passwordless SSH between any VMs.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet How?

Comment: Sorry, I only know Open MPI and am not familiar with GCE.